# How can I clip an infinite plane / polygon?

Tags: graphics3d, polygons, regions

What I'm looking to accomplish is for the tilted plane to not render for z<0.
[image: Graphics I'm working on]

I've tried using ClipPlanes and PlotRange options but InfinitePlane seems quite stubborn about rendering through the whole thing.
Also tried using BooleanRegion with the And function, a cuboid that covers z>0, and the plane.
I know in theory I could just find the appropiate points to define a polygon that draws what I want but there's probably an easier way.

Edit:
I've managed to clip the wrong side... with Style[polygon, ClipPlanes->InfinitePlane[...]]

Code:

```
\[Theta]i = \[Pi]/5;
\[Theta]t = ArcSin[Sin[\[Theta]i]/1.5];
\[Gamma] = \[Pi]/6;
Rx = ( {
    {1, 0, 0},
    {0, Cos[\[Theta]], -Sin[\[Theta]]},
    {0, Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]]}
   } );
Ry = ( {
    {Cos[\[Theta]], 0, Sin[\[Theta]]},
    {0, 1, 0},
    {-Sin[\[Theta]], 0, Cos[\[Theta]]}
   } );
Show[{
  Graphics3D[{
    Arrow[{{0, -1 Cos[\[Theta]i], 1 Sin[\[Theta]i]}, {0, 0, 0}}], 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[\[Theta]i], Sin[\[Theta]i]}}],
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[\[Theta]i - \[Pi]/2], 
       Sin[\[Theta]t - \[Pi]/2]}}],
    Black, Opacity[.3],
    InfinitePlane[{{0, -1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, -1}}],
    InfinitePlane[{{1, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}],
    Polygon[{{1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 
        0}} . (Ry /. \[Theta] -> \[Gamma] + \[Pi]/
           2) . (Rx /. \[Theta] -> \[Theta]i)]
    }, SphericalRegion -> True],
  ParametricPlot3D[(
    {0, t, (.1 Cos[
          20 t])} . (Ry /. \[Theta] -> \[Gamma]) . (Rx /. \[Theta] -> \
\[Theta]i) + {0, -1 Cos[\[Theta]i], 1 Sin[\[Theta]i]}
    ), {t, 0, 1}]
  }]
```

Comment: `Graphics3D[InfinitePlane[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]` does not display for `z < 0`. Edit your question to include copy and pasteable code that illustrates the problem you are having.

Comment: I updated the post :)

Comment: Add the options `PlotRange -> {0, Automatic},
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}` to the `Show`

Comment: `ClipPlanes -> {{0, 0, 1, 0}}`?

Comment: @cvgmt omg why does that even work?